# Best solution for managing unbounded number of fragments in Android

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, fragment, swipe

I want do develop an android application like google calendar. As you may have seen, in google calendar you can easily swipe between pages related to each day without any delay and even change the year and again swipe between days of that year with no delay in loading pages at all. I'm wondering what component is google calendar using for dealing with these potentially unbounded number of fragments? my guess is FragmentStatePagerAdapter but I'm not sure. having no delay (like google calendar) is my first priority.

Comment: Have you considered using `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);`?

Comment: and why do you think that is done using fragments?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Actually I have not tried anything yet since I don't know if ViewPager is the right solution, But I'll try it. thanks.

Comment: @pskink Because I need to define separate listeners for each page.

Comment: for that you dont need any fragments at all

Comment: @pskink What would you suggest then?

Comment: instead of `ViewPager`? use `RecyclerView` for example

Comment: I think you should try with `ViewPager`.